# Has many through relationship in Core Data / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I'm trying to recreate a has_many :through relationship (like in Rails) with Objective-C, if Core Data is backed by SQLite, this must be possible right? `<rant>` I could write the raw SQL for this in 2 seconds... `</rant>`

Anyway, basically here is a sub-set of my schema: TutorGroup ----< Allocation >---- Category, what I need to get is all categories that are allocated to a particular tutor group.

Here is my query so far:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(Allocation, $row, $row.tutor_group == %@ AND $row.category == <CURRENT_ROW>).@count > 0)", tutor_group];
```

Is there a way to represent the current row's object in a sub-query (where I've written `<CURRENT_ROW>` ? I've tried using `self` but that doesn't work.

Also, I'm assuming where I've put `Allocation` is the table name I want to perform the sub query on?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work, but try this:

```
ANY Allocation.TutorGroup = %@
```

Then pass in your tutor group using predicateWithFormat, and run it on Category.

Comment: This might work, but surely it'll be `ANY allocations.tutor_group == %@` (where `allocations` is a to-many relationship on Category, and `tutor_group` is a to-one relationship on Allocation), we'll see...

Comment: I think this is working now... bit hard to tell because it appears the allocations aren't being correctly stored because the `allocations.@count` is always returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way in CoreData is to have all the inverse relationships. Then you don't have to use predicates at all.

Having inverse relationships is really recommended... see [this official document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

So suppose the entity `TutorGroup` has a to-many relationship `allocations`, and `Allocation` has a to-one relationship `category`. 
Then

```
NSArray* categories = [tutor_group.allocations valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.category"];
```

See the discussion of collection operators [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178539).

Typically, when you use Core Data, you shouldn't use the knowledge that CoreData is backed by SQLite. That gives you a peace of your mind.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion seems to work, but I'll be needing the DB for other things so loading like this isn't really ideal. Thanks nevertheless :-)